# Tensorflow 2 TextVectorization - how to get the word frequencies

Tags: tensorflow

Is word frequency available from the TextVectorization instance? [TextVectorization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/TextVectorization) documentation says it determines the frequency of each string but it looks there is no method to get how many times a word appeared in the corpus it adapted.

> it will analyze the dataset, **determine the frequency of individual string values**, and create a 'vocabulary' from them.

If the TextVectorization instance has already analysed and has the word frequencies, we can use them for statistics e.g. for negative sampling. It can be done but prefer using already available information especially the corpus is large.

```py
from collections import Counter
corpus = "..."
total = len(words:=corpus.split())
probabilities = {word: (count / total) for (word, count) in Counter(words).items()}
```

Comment: It appears TextVectorization is a wrapper around [CategoryEncoding](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/preprocessing/text_vectorization.py#L355) which does [word counts](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/preprocessing/category_encoding.py#L293) on a per batch basis, so it doesn't seem that there is a way to get the frequency per word of the ***entire*** corpus from this class.